# How to provide default value for user input in PHP?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, readline

Is there a PHP functionallity same as `read -i` in BASH so that a script can prompt the user and provide a default answer like this:

```
Are you doing ok? (yes/no): yes
```

Where "*yes*" is the default answer provided by the script, which the user can erase and input another.

The [`readline`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) function does not seem to have what it takes. Is there any other way to do this?

Using a stream does not seem to work either:

```
<?php
echo "Are you doing ok? (yes/no): ";
$in = fopen('php://stdin', 'rw+');
fputs($in, 'yes'); // should be the default?
$answer = fgets($in);
fclose($in);
echo "\nYou entered: {$answer}\n";
```

Whatever is in written by the `fputs($in, 'yes');` line is ignored:

```
Are you doing ok? (yes/no): yes

You entered:
```

Am I using the stream incorrectly? Or maybe there is some other way to achive the default value?

EDIT:

Maybe I simlified the example to much. The real issue is not a simple `yes/no` prompt - this is just an example. Let me emphasize again: I'm aiming for providing **exactly the same** functionallity as the `read -i` BASH command. The `$answer` in my specific case holds an URL, so I would like for the user to be provided with the first part of the url (scheme, host, port), so he can add/edit the rest (path, query), fragment. Like this:

```
Enter url: http://www.example.com/foo/
```

now the user complement the path with `bar/baz` and we get:

```
You entered: http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz
```

But on the other hand the user also should have the option to erase the first part of the url and provide completely different string:

```
Enter url: ftp://www.my-super-specific-domain.com/foo/bar
```

Comment: @RonniSkansing: my thought as well, but turns out that the `fputs($in, 'yes');` actually **does output** the text.

Comment: yes but you can *not write* to the STDIN queue.

Comment: Ok, I get it. So are you saying that streams are completely off the table here?

Comment: =] I would only say writting to STDIN is off the table. I am sure you already read it, http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: PHP runs on a lot of different OSs. Obviously not all of them use BASH . And since `read -i` is a Linux/BASH feature PHP does not even _try_ to support it.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: I don't want to support it... (have I wrote something that mislead you?). I merely want to implement same functionality.

Comment: I was not talking about you, I was talking about PHP as a language. It does not even try to support writing to `stdin` as it is NOT a cross operating system feature and PHP is not primarily a CLI scripting language.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Ok, but `readline` is not a cross operating system feature as well, and yet when [compiled to PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php) it does provide the ability to write to `stdin` (only in some other fashion). So it might also provide what I need, right? Or perhaps other optional PHP extension might have what it takes? I'm open to such answers as well.

Comment: There's newt and ncurses support on Linux, but I don't think you want to go that far.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: Actually, since I'm building a CLI application I might consider using one of them. Thanks, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in way of doing this because writing some code that does it is quite straight forward:

```
function writeQuestion($question, $answers)
{
    echo $question . ' (' . implode('/', $answers) . '): ' . PHP_EOL;
}

function readAnswer($possibleAnswers, $defaultAnswer)
{
    $in = fopen('php://stdin', 'rw+');
    $answer = trim(fgets($in));

    if(!in_array($answer, $possibleAnswers))
    {
        return $defaultAnswer;
    }

    return $answer;
}

$question = 'Are you doing ok?';
$answers = array('yes', 'no');
$defaultAnswer = 'yes';

writeQuestion($question, $answers);
$answer = readAnswer($answers, $defaultAnswer);
```

Comment: Ok, this is somewhat near what I'm aming for, but the real issue is not a simple `yes/no` answer. The actual prompt is an url, which the user can edit to a point, and leave the first part as it is. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Forgot about the new line char at the end of `$answer` after reading it. We need a `trim` on it. But no, there's no way to write to `stdin` from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a standalone php cli file with function call to `read` command.
Little bit tricky, but hopefully will work as supposed to. :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

function xreadline ($prompt,$prefill)
{
  return exec ('/bin/bash -c ' . escapeshellarg('read -r -p ' . escapeshellarg($prompt) . ' -i ' . escapeshellarg($prefill) . ' -e STRING;echo "$STRING";'));
}

echo "Prompt test :\n";
$output =  xreadline ("edit this prefilled prompt: ","prefilled stuff");

echo "\n";

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap standard bash `read` for prefilled/populated edit, and call it from your main php cli script.

bash script named `xreadline`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
IFS=""
read -r -p "$1" -i "$2" -e STRING
echo "$STRING"
```

main php cli script:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

function xreadline ($prompt, $prefill)
{
  return exec ('./xreadline ' . escapeshellarg($prompt) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($prefill));
}

$answer = xreadline ('Your answer: ', 'xyz');
echo $answer;

...
```

This approach fully supports UTF8 instead of native PHP readline.

Comment: Thanks, but as the question states: I was looking for _PHP functionality_, so that it can be portable. What you're proposing is platform dependent.

Comment: This would be great for me, except that I'm getting confusing results with `read`. I can't find a man page for it (on Ubuntu Studio 16.04) that seems to reflect the actual executable on my computer, and the while entering `read -help` does force it to output available parameters (including `-i`), they're not explained at all. Using the script as written throws errors in PHP (`invalid option -i`), and doesn't fill in the default string when used natively on the command line :(.